I have a problem in yup validation when adding required and default value
My problem is I add validation schema on my formik form but the required() validation does not work if I put default("mmm") value
<Formik 
 initialValues={validtionShema.cast()} 
validationSchema={validtionShema} >

</Formik>

const validtionShema = Yup.object()
  .shape({
    name: Yup.string().default("@").required(),
    phone: Yup.number().integer().positive().min(1).default(0555).required(),
  })

so here required does not work if I remove default it will gonna work but in my case i should add a default value
the validation schema will work as expected
